# How to highlight syntax keywords in HTML with VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I don't know how I could highlight specific words in the HTML language, from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Is there a way to add this highlighting to an existing language?

Comment: What type of example is image #2? You have a block of code sitting inside the body tags which doesn't appear to be valid.

Comment: I am creating a simple template engine, the syntax of image # 2 will be read and converted by node js, `Button` is a Function that will generate the html of a button, it can also receive arguments (arrays, objects, numbers, etc.).

Comment: That idea has been brought up and used for quite some time already (see React and Angular for example). Why inventing yet another such language?